# Многопоточность в С++. В чем отличие pthread от std::thread?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, pthread

В чем основные отличия posix threads и класса std::thread? В каком случае что выбрать и почему? Желательно, поподробнее.

Comment: На posix-совместимых системах `std::thread` это обертка над pthread.

Comment: По крайней мере в \*nix `std::thread` это надстройка над подмножеством функций `pthreads`.

Comment: std::thread является частью стандартной библиотеки с++, с его помощью вы сможете писать кроссплатформенный код. В конечном итоге на каждой из ОС std::thread будет взаимодействовать с функциями ОС по маипулированию потоками (будь-то WinAPi, phthread или еще что). Так что если у вас нет нужды в использовании специфичных для phthread  функций, то следует использовать std::thread

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25221247/c11-stdthread-vs-windows-createthread